# EGOTextView sample

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, editing, richtext

I've been playing with `EGOTextView` for an iOS project and have been able to get some very basic edit done. Is really cool how it can plug into place of `UITextView`. But now I'm afraid that I don't understand properly how to completely use. Is anyone knowing of a sample using of `EGOTextView` for rich text edit?

Comment: same thing to me. I can not find any differences in his demo

Comment: You can contact on this, Already mention on git Repo.

Feel free to contact info@enormego.com if you need any help with EGOTextView.

Answer (score 1):

You may call these method of EGOTextView

- (void)setFont:(UIFont *)font
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
- (void)setAttributedString:(NSAttributedString*)string
- (void)setEditable:(BOOL)editable
- (void)drawContentInRect:(CGRect)rect
- (NSInteger)closestWhiteSpaceIndexToPoint:(CGPoint)point
- (NSInteger)closestIndexToPoint:(CGPoint)point
- (NSRange)characterRangeAtPoint_:(CGPoint)point
- (NSRange)characterRangeAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
- (void)setCorrectionRange:(NSRange)range
- (void)setLinkRange:(NSRange)range
- (UIColor*)selectionColor
- (UITextPosition*)positionFromPosition:(UITextPosition *)position offset:(NSInteger)offset
- (void)deleteBackward
- (void)checkLinksForRange:(NSRange)range
- (void)checkSpellingForRange:(NSRange)range
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
- (void)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
- (void)spellingCorrection:(UIMenuController*)sender

According to your need, there much more method call remain.